# PowerBI groupby and summarizing

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataframe like shown below in PowerBI:

```
Date             Store    Group    Value
01 April 2015    1000     Fish     98
```

How can I write a DAX code to aggregate the rows and group by Store, Group and Date (over year quaters) and sum up the Values. I would like to have the date column to be a yearquarter column in the format: 2014 Q1.

Comment: Have you looked into [Summarize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarize-function-dax)?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

First, create a 'Year Qtr' field by adding a calculated column to your table:

```
YearQtr =
YEAR ( 'Table'[Date] ) & " "
    & CONCATENATE ( "Q", CEILING ( MONTH ( 'Table'[Date] ) / 3, 1 ) )
```

Then, you can create a calculated table using the following DAX:

```
AggTable:=
SUMMARIZE (
    'Table',
    'Table'[Store],
    'Table'[Group],
    'Table'[YearQtr],
    "Sum", SUM ( 'Table'[Value] )
)
```

Hope it helps!